# how to achieve the behavior of :silent !a.out in vim

Tags: term

I am on terminal.

I'd like to invoke a ncurses based program `a.out`. In vim, I do `:silent !a.out`, which will **directly** show `a.out`.

In emacs, the closest thing I can do is `(suspend-emacs "a.out")`. However, the parent terminal will first be shown, and then `a.out` will be launched. It is as if we literally first suspend emacs, and type `a.out`, hence showing the original content on the terminal, losing the **silent** benefit as in vim.

Comment: Is `M-&` what you're looking for?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 the ncurses program need to be in the front; it's a tui tool, and cannot be in the background.

Comment: Try `M-x term` in that case.